# how to monitor the exting of Application?

Tags: android

How to monitor the exiting of Application by fullscreen slide up posture？in some mobiles the method onUserLeaveHint() doesn't invoked.So are there methods to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `mainActivity` or any other activities callbacks, you could know when the user is exiting the app.

When the user leaves the app `onStop` is called (your activity is not visible to the user anymore). and when activity is destroyed( app shuts down) `onDestory` is called.

```
    override fun onDestroy() {
        /* insert code here */
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

for more info visit [Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)